# dateComponents() from... to in days shows from now to tomorrow as 0 days?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatecomponents

I have datecomponent objects that represent some time in the future. I want to calculate how many dates from now until that date. I'm also including representation of the dates simply as dates. What I'm finding is that when I am trying to show how many there are to a date that is 'tomorrow' it's showing 0. To my mind it should be showing 1. I can try a hacky way of just adding 1 to my count but I'm wondering is it because it's trying to round to the nearest 24 hours or something? If so how can I 'fix' it?

Here is my sample code:
`let myPreviousRelevantDate = self.datePickerOutlet.date`

```
let nextDate = Date(timeInterval: Double(86400 * (myDurationInDaysAsInt)), since: myPreviousRelevantDate!)

let daysToNextDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: nextDate).day!
```

What I'd like to avoid is the number of days to the target date changing during the day also - i.e. regardless of the timestamp of my target date - the number of days to that day remaining constant until midnight is reached.

Comment: How are  `myPreviousRelevantDate` and `myDurationInDaysAsInt` calculated?

Comment: you can see why when you use this: `let h = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date(), to: nextDate).hour!` and print it, it (probably) gives you 23 hours, or something less than 24 hours.

Comment: @meaning-matters - have updated, essentially I pull the .date from a datepicker.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I sort of suspected that might be the case, but my question is what is the recommended way to get the number of days between two dates in this case? Where a day means beyond midnight rather than 24 hours?

Comment: If your intent is to calculate the number of days using a timeless calendrical calculation what you need is to use noon time.

Comment: Oh I never heard of noon time, I'll do some research and check it out. Thanks @LeoDabus. The other thought I had was if I had a way to 'floor' the datepicker's time when it gets recorded perhaps - so effectively trim the time from it or zero it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intent is to calculate the number of days using a timeless calendrical calculation what you need is to use noon time. Note that not every day has 24 hours, you should always use calendar method to add days to a date:

```
extension Date {
    var noon: Date {
        Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
            .date(
                bySettingHour: 12,
                minute: 0,
                second: 0,
                of: self
            )!
    }
}
```

---

```
let daysToNextDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date().noon, to: nextDate.noon).day!
```

Comment: Simple & Smart.